# Menu cannot be showed within DIV with specific width defined

Tags: css, wordpress

I added a horizational menu in a header of WordPress within a `<nav id="hoz-menu">` I have no idea which CSS statement make the menu exceed the block. It is supposed the CSS of the menu is responsive. 
Demo can be found from http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/nqx2a1ao/

Here is the screen capture of the Chrome debug http://screencloud.net/v/Ernf

Below is HTML code of the menu

```
<nav id="hoz-menu">
    <ul id="hoz-menu" class="topmenu">
        <li class="topfirst"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;"><span>Item 1</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;"><span>Item 2</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.5</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;">Item 4</a></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;">Item 5</a></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;">Item 6</a></li>
        <li class="toplast"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;">Item 7</a></li>
    </ul>                   
</nav>
```

the width of `<nav id="hoz-menu">` is 420px and CSS is

```
{
    display: block;
}
```

CSS of `<ul id="hoz-menu" class="topmenu">`

```
#hoz-menu ul#hoz-menu, ul#hoz-menu ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
background-color: #dedede;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #5f5f5f;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: The block is too small, that's why your menu is outside the block. I don't see the problem?

Comment: It suppose the menu will be resized according to the width of the block.